# Create a zip file using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, zip

I am trying to create a logic app that gets triggered when a file is uploaded in an FTP server. The logic app then needs to fetch this file along with another file which is present in a blob storage and create a zip file out of them and then place in some blob storage. Since I am new to logic apps, I am not sure how to create a zip file from these files and place it in another blob. Can anyone please help me here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For now, Compress/Zip files is not supported, you could upvote this feedback: [Compress/Zip folder/file to archive](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/31748887-compress-folder-to-archive), however the status of this feedback shows they already start to implement this feature.

Or you could try to use a third party connector: encodian. Further more details about how to use this action you could refer to this tutorial: [ADD TO ARCHIVE (ZIP)](https://support.encodian.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360002674918-Add-to-Archive-ZIP-).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even we have to create .zip in our project as we are not able to use Blob, we are using SFTP server as solution in our project.
[image]
[image]